# I want to launch main activity after splash screen instead of login screen

Tags: android

In my code Login screen comes after the splash screen but I want to launch the main activity, I have mentioned the android XML below.

```
  <application
        android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Util.YouApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.Login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.Register"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.ForgetPassword"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.AboutUs" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.PrivacyPolicy" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.Profile" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.EditProfile" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.BookDetail" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.CategoryByList" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.AllComment" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.RelatedBook" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.Find" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.PDFShow" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.AuthorByList" />
        <activity android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Activity.ReportBook" />

        <service
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Util.NotificationExtenderExample"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.growthapple.ebooks.Util.DownloadService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: in splash screen startactivity using Intent with Mainactivity screen

Comment: Show the intent of placed in the SplashScreen for redirection

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write logic at splash activity to check weather the user is already Logged-In or not, if Logged-In then show the Home Screen otherwise show Login Screen.

```
 public void waitDecideAndShowView(final int milliseconds) {
    if (repository.getStorage().getPreference().getUserInfo() == null)
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> view.showLogin(), milliseconds);
    else
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> view.showHome(), milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want to show the Home screen at app startup after splash screen whether the user is logged in or not, what can I do for this?

Comment: For that write startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class)); in splash activity class

Answer (score 0):

My Tip would be to re-order your navigation to something like this:

> SplashScreen -> MainActivity -> LoginActivity.

**Explanation:**

Your SplashScreen takes you to MainActivity, MainActivity verifes if the user is
logged in or not, if he is then he stays there, else navigate to LoginActivity.

This is called Conditional Navigation, read more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want to show the Home screen at app startup after splash screen whether the user is logged in or not, what can I do for this?

Comment: I see. So you would only need to change the Condition for the Navigation, in the answer I posted remove the condition, and only navigate to the Login Screen when the user performs the action that you want, either a button click or something else

Answer (score 0):

In Splash Screen Activity write

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },2000); // your can set time delay according to your requirment
```